# TFS Error for BuildDetail.BuildServer.TeamFoundationServer.Uri

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

We have customised xaml template for one of build definition and while migrating it to 64Bit.

> Error Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.BuildServer.TeamFoundationServer.Uri". 'TeamFoundationServer' is not a member of 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer'.

Comment: What TFS version are you using? What does the assembly reference section in the XAML code look like? OPen it in Notepad and copy it to this question (just the assembly reference section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to re-add all assembly references in your code project for the template and re-build it to see whether you would get any error.
2. Try `buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.Uri` instead of `BuildDetail.BuildServer.TeamFoundationServer.Uri`.